# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when using PWA - ReactJs on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, netlify

I have a problem that only occurs in the application hosted on netlify, basically I have a website in ReactJs and there was a need to add PWA so that the application could work offline.

Everything works normally online, but when I install the site and try to open it offline, this error occurs even though everything necessary for it to work offline is correctly stored in the cache. (this error does not happen online or offline when installing the application via localhost. only on netlify)

Has anyone had a similar problem and know how to fix it?

how to reproduce the error:

Access the website https://computacaoplugadaordenacao.netlify.app/ with an active internet connection
2.Click install in the browser

3 Try opening the application without an internet connection

repository:https://github.com/Marcos-Vinicius9/sorting-plugged-computing-web